# Why we need the optional parameter queryItem in Cognos promptmany

Tags: cognos

In this page:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_fm.8.4.0.doc/ug_fm_id9744using_macro.html
We have:

```
QueryItem
This parameter is optional. The prompt engine can take advantage of the Prompt Info properties of the query item. Descriptive information can be shown, although the prompt value is a code.
```

I am having trouble understanding this part :

```
The prompt engine can take advantage of the Prompt Info properties of the query item. Descriptive information can be shown, although the prompt value is a code.
```

The promptmany syntax will ultimately generate a where clause. So how can it use the properties of the Query Item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prompt generation in the front end uses this parameter, not the query engine. This parameter makes no difference to the where clause. It is basically a hint to the prompt engine to tell the front end when it tries to automatically build a prompt.

I never fill in this parameter when I use prompt macros.